# Deleting pictures from my SkyDrive

Tags: photos, onedrive

I currently have a new Windows phone and EVERY picture I take is downloaded in my Pictures file named SkyDrive cameral roll from Windows Live.  I do not want every picture I take downloaded onto SkyDrive and want to delete the file.

How do I keep my pictures from automatically downloading and how do I delete the file from my phone.  It does not give me the option to do so on the phone itself.

Comment: [turn off the autoupload](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wptips/how-to-remove-the-default-uploading-of-photos-onto/05891ee4-db07-4bdf-a6f7-849b86b3c107)

Comment: Have you tried connecting to Zune to delete the files from your phone?